# add space in between output in php

Tags: php, html, space

I'm trying to add a space in beetwen my php, I need to add a space after the output and remove the comma at the last output. Here is my code

```
<div id="demo-1" data-zs-src='[
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM slider ORDER BY no_urut ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "\"images/slideshow/".$data['img']."\",";
        }
    }
    ?>
]' data-zs-overlay="dots"></div>
```

and when I'm run that code, it goes like this

```
data-zs-src="["images/slideshow/img1.jpg","images/slideshow/img2.jpg","images/slideshow/img3.jpg",]"
```

but I want the code to goes like this

```
data-zs-src="["images/slideshow/img1.jpg", "images/slideshow/img2.jpg", "images/slideshow/img3.jpg"]"
```

Comment: In addition to this, you'll probably want to use single-quotes for your array. Otherwise, `data-zs-src` will just evaluate to `"["` (with the rest of the array throwing a syntax error).

Comment: You should use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) instead, also why do it inline? Plus if you're only using `img` column why return all `*`?

Answer (score 0):

You can make assignments and checked in a single if statement, form an array using the results, then implode with `,` (comma space).

```
<div id="demo-1" data-zs-src="[
    <?php
    if($result=mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT `img` FROM `slider` ORDER BY `no_urut` ASC;') && mysqli_num_rows($result)){
        while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $imgs[]="\"images/slideshow/{$data['img']}\"";
        }
        echo implode(', ',$imgs);
    }
    ?>
]" data-zs-overlay="dots"></div>
```

Or with your original one-liner style:

```
<div id="demo-1" data-zs-src="[<?php if($result=mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT `img` FROM `slider` ORDER BY `no_urut` ASC;') && mysqli_num_rows($result)){while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){$imgs[]="\"images/slideshow/{$data['img']}\"";}; echo implode(', ',$imgs);}?>]" data-zs-overlay="dots"></div>
```